# select * tablename returns datetime with two different format

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need some advice about retrieving records from data table.
I have one table contain column **dateDBO** as **DateTime**.I use select query like `select * from tblUsers` in two different scenario.Where in one(server) I get the dateDBO format like `01/01/2012 12:00:00 AM` and in other(local) scenario I get like `01-Jan-00 12:00:00 AM`.

Can any body please tell me how this is happen I know I can get this fix by specifying the particular column name with **Cast or Convert**,but this `select * tblUsers` return me some mysterious result how ??

*I am calling this from my asp.net (3.5) application.

thanks in advance.

sorry for English.

**Update** :: The same code when I deployed on the server is reflecting the date `01/01/2012 12:00:00 AM` this but on my local its like `01-Jan-00 12:00:00 AM`.So I am confuse that this is due to some Date & Time setting change and how this date time change affect to asp.net selection.
my .net code

```
//set the command
objCommand = new OleDbCommand(strQueryText, objConnection);
//set the command type
objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OleDbDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new leDbDataAdapter(objCommand); 
DataSet objLcDataSet = new DataSet(); 
objDataAdapter.FillSchema(objLcDataSet, SchemaType.Mapped); 
int lngRetVal = objDataAdapter.Fill(objLcDataSet);
```

Result Data ::

```
dateDBO
1959-11-05 00:00:00.000 
1965-12-13 00:00:00.000 
1979-08-01 00:00:00.000 
1972-02-15 00:00:00.000 
1978-12-23 00:00:00.000 
1985-09-04 00:00:00.000 
1986-04-19 00:00:00.000 
1966-03-10 00:00:00.000 
1959-08-30 00:00:00.000
```

I would like to ask you all,the **Regional Option** field in **Control Panel** will affect to the query output ??

when I change this I found the result same as I get on the server.

Comment: What is the client that is querying the data? It is probably best to use the language features of the client instead of formatting in SQL.

Comment: are all datatype of `dateDBO` datetime?

Comment: can you post some data from the table and are you using only sql to do this ?

Comment: @ashutosh raina - sorry but this table contains lot much data but I can share the dateDBO records,is that ok?

Comment: do you want to convert the column into two diffrerent format?

Comment: @KuyaJohn no I just want,how this is happen?Is this is by default issue or I did some changes so that this is happening.

Comment: agree JohnFx that you should do it in .Net instead

Comment: @gofor.net: Kindly edit your question. This section is used to just comment on the topics.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), dateDBO , 6) , ' ', '-') AS [DD-Mon-YY],  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateDBO , 108) as [HH:MM:SS], substring(convert(varchar(30), dateDBO , 9), 25, 2) from tblUser

Then you need to plus these three columns.

For more information, see
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

Comment: ,I can use this but I want to know this occurs due to some setting done by me or this is some bug or issue??

Comment: I don't think it is bug or issue. If you want to do something special rather than default setting, just use convert function.
BTW, I would like do this in front by operating DateTime class, it should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
dataset.table[0].rows[0]["dateDBO"].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");